# Simple excercises for learning a new language

Tags: language-agnostic

I remember stumbling onto a list of basic algorithms to implement in a new language to get your head around how the language does thing, but I seem to have lost the link to it.

What simple tasks/code snippets would you recomend one undertakes to pick get a good feeling of a language?

I'm not talking developing large applications or anything the kind of things I'm thinking about are writing a linked list then extending it to a doubly linked list. Implementing various sort/search algorithms, etc.

Excercises that would help somone who knows how to program in one language get up to speed as quickly as possible in a new language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually take a couple of random problems from Project Euler: http://projecteuler.net/

Comment: These exercises are mainly from a mathematical background. That's nice but I think you can learn more about a new programming language if you go for a wider scope.

Comment: @lutz: yes, I agree. But they are quite challenging and interesting, and you get nice feeling of accomplishment when you submit a solution and it's accepted as a correct one :)

Answer (score 4):

I like the exercises from [CodeKata](http://codekata.pragprog.com/2007/01/code_kata_backg.html). They are not too easy and not too difficult. Strech your mind with them!

Answer (score 2):

I really do like the [problems](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/classical/) at [spoj.pl](http://www.spoj.pl/). Can be done in quite some lanuages. Yours may be one of those.

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere that creating a Blog is the HelloWorld 2.0, I saw you don't want big applications but I found worth to share this

Answer (score 1):

You might try [this list from JobSnake](http://www.jobsnake.com/seek/articles/index.cgi?openarticle&8533) to familiarize yourself with a new programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to write compiler/interpreter for it.  This opens up many obscure corners of the language and also makes you understand the reasons behind features of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime I have/want to learn a new project, I force myself to find something to code.

But to be sure I did it well, I always want to be able to check my code and what it ouputs.

To do so, I just try to do the same kind of stuff with languages I know and to compare the outputs. For that, I created a little project (hosted on [Github](https://github.com/MrST4N/ProgrammingLearning/)) with an exercise sheet and the correction for every language I learnt. It's a good way to learn in my opinion because it gives you a real little project.